# Parse.com PFQuery order by time

Tags: swift, parse-platform

In my parse.com "Posts" it looks like this:
[image: From Parse.com]

And my Query looks like this:

```
func QueryImagesFromParse(){
        var query = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil
            {
                if let newObjects = objects as? [PFObject] {

                    for oneobject in newObjects {
                        var text = oneobject["imageText"] as! String
                        var username = oneobject["username"] as! String
                        var time = oneobject.createdAt
                        var userImageFile = oneobject["imageFile"] as! PFFile
                        userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData:NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                            if error == nil {
                                let newImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)

                                var OneBigObject = Details(username: username, text: text, CreatedAt: time!, image: newImage!)
                                self.arrayOfDetails.append(OneBigObject)

                                self.collectionView.reloadData()
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

NSDate Extension:

```
extension NSDate {
    var timeAgo: String {
        let minute = 60
        let hour = 60 * minute
        let day = 24 * hour
        let secondsAgo = Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(self))
        if secondsAgo < 0            { return  "later"                           }
        if secondsAgo == 0           { return "now"                              }
        if secondsAgo == 1           { return "1 second ago"                     }
        if secondsAgo < minute       { return "\(secondsAgo) seconds ago"        }
        if secondsAgo < (2 * minute) { return "1 minute ago"                     }
        if secondsAgo < hour         { return "\(secondsAgo/minute) minutes ago" }
        if secondsAgo < 2 * hour     { return "1 hour ago"                       }
        if secondsAgo < day          { return "\(secondsAgo / hour) hours ago"   }
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "M/d/yy"
        return formatter.stringFromDate(self)
    }
}
```

I have tried using the `query.orderByDescending` to sort the newest upload on the top, but it does not work.. The uploads comes in random order, and not by newest first. What am i doing wrong? I am running the `func QueryImagesFromParse` in my viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

The getDataInBackgroundWithBlock method you are using to get userImageFile and then append OneBigObject is asynchronous so your array is not guaranteed to be in the correct order.

Try removing that method and using this instead:

```
let imageData = userImageFile.getData()
```

Comment: I tried adding that after the "getDataInBackgroundWithBlock" method, and that made it work. But i get a lot of error messages in the output on runtime: Look here: http://s27.postimg.org/evypc1hs3/Screen_Shot_2015_09_09_at_12_25_10.png

Comment: Synchronous methods are generally not recommended as they block the UI. I assume you are downloading the image data to display in a UIImageView. In that case, I would skip getting the imageData here and instead use a library like [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) (Swift) or [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) (Objective-C) for async image loading when you need to display the image.

Comment: @Eri-Sklii Forgot to tag you in the comment above.